# Who is Mata Parvati's daughter?

Tags: parvati

In some places Mata Parvati has Ashok Sundari as her daughter and in some places Saraswati and Laxmi? Which one is believed more?

Comment: Um...y is it that I cannot tag anything other than Parvati??

Comment: How can Sarasvati or lakshami can be daughter of Parvati?? Both were exist way more earlier than Parvati. When there were not even name of Parvati exist, even then Mahaa maya Lakshami and Saraswati were there. Both of their existence are even older than the existence of world. So on what basis they can be daughter of Parvati. Its baseless thought. Ashok Sundari is real daughter of Parvati. Besides Parvati is sister of Vishnu, not mother in-law!!

Comment: Yeah even I was thinking the same.

Comment: Well. Agajaa is not directly the mother of Vaani and SindhuNandini. HimaSutaa has created all the God and Goddesses in the sense that She is the Ultimate Shakti. 
So She is rather their Creatrix  than Mother. Similarly there are stories of AdiShakti creating ChaturAnana, PadmaMukha, and PanchaVaktra. But it is mere Leela of God, which is not comprehended. ChandraShekhara, KaustubhaDhara, and PadmaJa, were never born nor they die. Similarly, SarasWati, Lakshmi, Parvati are never born nor created.

Answer (score 1):

All are symbolic representation of God's form. Maa Sakthi, Maa lakshmi and Maa Sarasawathi manifested by Maa Aathi Sakthi. From these three mother goddess, there are lot of Goddess manifested. Goddess Asoka Sundari(have some other name manonmani, bala thirupura sundari, vaalai) is form of maa sakthi who is so young(age 9, believed in some place, her age is 12, believed in some places). 
So she is treated as Daughter of Maa Parvathi. It is like incarnation or manifestation. Simply Asoke sundari is child form of maa Shakthi.